# npm install: npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/axios reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: npm, eslint

I have a gatsby portfolio application and had to do some updates to it. Then cloned it from github and had to install dependencies. When i run `npm install` i have the error log below:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-flowtype@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-flowtype
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-flowtype@"3.x || 4.x" from eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm WARN   eslint-config-react-app@"^5.2.1" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-react@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-react
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-react@"7.x" from eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm WARN   eslint-config-react-app@"^5.2.1" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-react-hooks@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"1.x || 2.x" from eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm WARN   eslint-config-react-app@"^5.2.1" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: graphql@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/graphql
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer graphql@"^14.4.1" from express-graphql@0.9.0
npm WARN node_modules/express-graphql
npm WARN   express-graphql@"^0.9.0" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: graphql@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/graphql
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer graphql@"^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0" from express-graphql@0.6.12
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/express-graphql
npm WARN   express-graphql@"^0.6.6" from gatsby@1.9.279
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: graphql@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/graphql
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer graphql@"^0.5.0 || ^0.6.0 || ^0.7.0 || ^0.8.0-b || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0" from graphql-relay@0.5.5
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/graphql-relay
npm WARN   graphql-relay@"^0.5.1" from gatsby@1.9.279
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-source-strapi/node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/axios reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I have cleared the cache using `npm cache clean --force` and ran `npm install` again but I still have same error....

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/axios reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Any help how I can fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.21.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-webfonts": "^1.1.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.4.2",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-strapi": "0.0.12",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Comment: add you package.json here

Comment: I will edit the original post and add the `package.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem from your side. It is not a problem of `package.json`. In the `ERR`, the URL `https://registry.npmjs.org/axios` (last line of the error message) gives a JSON response which is flawed. See the below image. The JSON validation fails. They must resolve this.

Try running

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
yarn
```

Or try uninstalling and then reinstalling.

#### EDIT:

Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `lock` file. Then try running `yarn`

If you don't have `yarn` installed install it by using

```
npm i -g yarn
```

Check the installation using

```
yarn --version
```

[image]

Comment: I get this when I run `npm cache clean --force` 
`npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`
When I run `npm cache verify` I get the results below:
```
npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.009s
```

Comment: Did it install now?

Comment: it did not install

Comment: Ok, No problem. Find it here - `https://github.com/t-yanick/tazoh-portfolio`

Comment: Just a minute. I am just running `yarn` with just `package.json`

Comment: It is working fine here. See this https://pastebin.com/E7f9zBd7. See the edit in the answer

Comment: What am I supposed to do to fix the issue at my end. I don't really understand your solution. Thanks

Comment: Inside your project, there will be a folder called `node_modules`. Delete this. There will also be a lock file ending in `.lock`. Delete this too.
Then run this command: `npm i -g yarn` Then at the root of the project (i.e. where your `package.json` is located), run this command: `yarn`

Comment: I don't have `node_modules` and `.lock` since i cloned the repo from github. after running `npm i -g yarn` this is what i get npm i -g yarn
```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/el/.npm/_logs/2021-05-10T08_38_43_747Z-debug.log
```

Comment: That's not a problem. This means that `yarn` is already installed. Now, inside the project directory, just run `yarn` (make sure that you are in the path where the `package.json`)

Comment: running `yarn` fixed the issue. Thanks very much @JohnBrookfields